# Ubuntu 19.10: How to set automatic disappearance of notifications

Tags: gnome, notification

I recently switched to Ubuntu 19.10. I followed a guide to activate the "Fullscreen Notifications" shell extension, so as to get notification pop-ups, for example, while watching a movie. However, I have a problem: I'd like the pop-ups to disappear by themselves after a number of seconds, while currently they do not go away without a mouse movement. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: the problem occurred even before the extension was installed. However, this is the link of the extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1610/fullscreen-notifications/

Comment: What about linking to the extension and the guide so we know what you are talking about?

Comment: I've edited the post.